# Unity3D audio playback only once when the clip is fed in at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

It seems that despite setting `audiosource.loop=false` it isn't possible to have an audio clip that is loaded at runtime into an audio source stop looping???

Surely, this must be possible...

Comment: How, when and where are you playing the sound? You need to show some code and explain....

Comment: Audiosource displays audio without loop by default anyway :S

Comment: Have you tried audioSource.PlayOneShot({AudioClip: clip}, {float: volumeScale})?